# Why animate() does not work?

Tags: jquery

If I use .CSS() instead of .animate(), it works.

### Examples:

```
function resizedWindow(){       
    if($(window).width() < 400){
       $('#someId').animate({color:'red'},1000);    
    }
    else{
       $('#someId').animate({color:'blue'},1000);
    }
}
```

---

does not work!

---

```
function resizedWindow(){       
    if($(window).width() < 400){
       $('#someId').css({'color':'red'});   
    }
    else{
       $('#someId').css({'color':'blue'});
    }
}
```

---

it works!

Answer (score 3):

You will need to include JQuery UI to animate color properties. JQuery cannot animate color properties out of the box by itself.

Comment: To further this, I'd also consider using the .addClass() method with the jQuery UI animation instead of setting CSS inside the JS file. Example: `$('#someId').addClass('active', 500);` and in the CSS you'd have `#someId.active {color: red;}`

Comment: He is trying to animate property. So either the code he wrote or the jQuery UI switchClass() method would animate properties.

Answer (score 0):

As Ananthan stated, you cannot animate color properties with jQuery animate without jQuery UI.

One alternative would be to use .css(), and add a CSS transition:

```
#someId {
  -webkit-transition: color 1s linear; 
     -moz-transition: color 1s linear; 
       -o-transition: color 1s linear; 
          transition: color 1s linear; 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Check your jQuery UI version (if you're loading it, otherwise, go with ananthan's answer first and try loading jQuery UI).  I was playing around with this in JSFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/5wZ2J/2/ :

HTML:

```
<div  id="changeAnimate" style="color:red;">
    some red stuff
</div>
<div style="color:red;" id="changeme">
    some red stuff
</div>
```

JS:

```
$(function(){
    $("#changeAnimate").animate({color: "blue"}, 1000 );
    $("#changeme").css({'color':'blue'});   
});
```

I noticed that sometimes it was getting finicky in some combinations of jQuery / jQuery UI.

Answer (score 0):

thank you all for the quick responses. Thanks to Robert for good tip, I achieved what I wanted. Here is a code. And, it works ;)

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $(window).bind('resize',resizedWindow);
});

    function resizedWindow(){   


        if($(window).width() < 400){
          $('#someId').css({
                color: 'red',
                transition:'all 3s linear'
        });

        }
        else{
          $('#someId').css({
                color: 'blue',
                transition:'all 3s linear'
        });
        }

    }
```